# Node: Better way to provide arguments to module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to provide arguments to a module. My module doesn't return any functions / objects.

Currently I provide those arguments with

#### App

```js
require('./path/to/module')(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

#### Module

```js
module.exports = (arg1, arg2, ...) => {
  ...
  return {}; 
};
```

I was wondering if there is a better suited way of providing arguments to that module.

Comment: Better suited for what? Is there any problem with the current approach?

Comment: "*My module doesn't return any functions / objects.*" - that doesn't sound like a module. If your factory doesn't create anything, then what *does* it do? Does your code rely on side effects only?

Comment: @Bergi It extends an event emitter provided by a different library. There is nothing wrong with the current approach either.

Comment: By "extends", you mean it manipulates it? So if your function is called multiple times, it will do weird things?